# How to execute test Method by gradle test task?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testng, build.gradle

> When i run my testing.xml as testNG suit its run properly but when run
>   gradle test task it doesn't execute test
>
> testing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT" name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.example.EmpBusinessLogicTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

> build.gradle
>
> buildscript {
>         ext {
>             springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
>         }
>         repositories {
>             mavenCentral()
>         }
>         dependencies {
>             classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
>         }
>       }
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'java'
> apply plugin: 'eclipse'
> apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
>
> jar {
>   baseName = 'demo'
>   version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
> }
> sourceCompatibility = 1.8
> targetCompatibility = 1.8
>
>
> repositories {
>   mavenCentral()
> }
>
>
> dependencies {
>   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
>   testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
>   compile('org.testng:testng:6.9.10')
>
> }
>
> test {
>     useTestNG() 
>     {        
>         suites 'src/main/resources/testing.xml'
>
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> can anyone help me to execute gradle test task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As option you can generate xml directly in gradle in test task, it works fine in our project

```
useTestNG() {
    suiteXmlBuilder().suite(name: 'Default suite') {
        test(name : 'test') {
            classes('') {
                'class'(name: 'com.example.EmpBusinessLogicTest')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To execute this test task e.g. with Jenkins you will need to pass system properties to it:

```
systemProperties System.getProperties()
systemProperty 'user.dir', project.projectDir
```